# Prompt box to re-create itself until correct field has been entered

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've got some code for a Javascript alert. I want my client to be able to enter a code to access an area of my website.

At the moment I have some JS code that if a user enters the wrong credentials an alert box is created and a user selects okay and it goes to the website anyway. This is not ideal.

How can I have a loop that re-creates the prompt box until the correct credential (variable `x`) is supplied.

```
   window.onload = function launch() {
            var x = "name of credential";
            var person = prompt("The website is under development\nPlease enter your development code:");
            if (person == x) {
                alert("Success!");
                <?php header("Location : index.php");?>
            } 
            else {
                alert("You have entered the wrong credentials please try again!");
                var person = prompt("The Care Socierty website is under development\nPlease enter your development code:");
            }
```

**Krishna's suggestion**

```
    window.onload = function launch() {
            var x = "credential";
            var person = prompt("The website is under development\nPlease enter your development code:");
            if (person == x) {
                alert("Success!");
                window.location;
            } 
            else {
                alert("You have entered the wrong credentials please try again!");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Dont use php `header()` function. use `window.location` instead.And to stop navigating from this page use `return false;` after `alert()`

Comment: you mean `return false` in the `else` clause?

Comment: Yes in the `else` part only

Comment: Not exactly related, but this snippet won't prevent "outsiders" to navigate to the page under developement. It will take only few seconds to check a correct "password" from the source code. A solution to the question would be for example [`do..while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) loop.

Comment: Just to add, I hope you are aware that anyone can easily find that 'code' by looking at the source of your page. I would recommend securing a site in development with htaccess and htpasswd.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that but thank you for your concern :)

Comment: @user3169859 you should write like this `window.location=index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a loop in order to iterate you code

Try this one it might help you

```
window.onload = function () {
  var x = "name of credential";
  var wrong = true;

  while (wrong) {
    var person = prompt("The website is under development\nPlease enter your development code:");
    if (person == x) {
      alert("Success!");
      wrong = false;
      <?php header("Location : index.php");?>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude working perfectly :) I knew a `boolean` operator would come into play at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
if (person == x) {
  alert("Success!");
  window.location = 'index.php';
} // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keeps prompting you need to do something like this.

Try here : http://jsbin.com/duroguji/2/edit

```
$(function () {
  setTimeout(askPermission,1000);
});

function askPermission()
{
  var success = false;
  var x = "HELLO";
  while(!success)
    {
  var person = prompt("The website is under development\nPlease enter your development     code:", "");
  if (person == x) {
    success = true;
    alert("Success!");
  } 
  else {
    alert("You have entered the wrong credentials please try again!");
    setTimeout(askPermission,1000);
  }
  }
}
```